Why document isn't persisted in mongodb during repository save?
I have Spring-boot + spring-data-mongodb application.
I have collection
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Document(collection = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @Field("id")
    private String id;
    @Field(name = "messageType", targetType = FieldType.STRING)
    private MessageType messageType;
    @Indexed
    @NotBlank(message = "requestId is mandatory")
    @Field("requestId")
    private String requestId;
    @Indexed
    @NotBlank(message = "Recipient(to) field is mandatory")
    @Field("to")
    private String to;
    @Indexed
    @NotBlank(message = "Sender(from) field is mandatory")
    @Field("from")
    private String from;
    @Field("text")
    private String text;
    @Field("img")
    private List<MessageImage> images;
    @Field("offer")
    private Offer offer;
    @CreatedDate
    @Field("createdAt")
    private Instant createdAt;
}

I need to implement image upload and image message save. Fact is that image service is a separate service, which accepts base64 images and its also needs id of my message. So what I have to do:
1 persist raw message to make mongo generate id automatically
2 send image data+messageId
3 process response from image service and update existing message document.
Here is my code:
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends MongoRepository<Message, String> {
}

@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;
    private final MessageMapper messageMapper;
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private final MessageImageService messageImageService;
public Message createMessage(@Valid MessageRequestDTO messageRequestDTO) {
        Message message = messageMapper.toEntity(messageRequestDTO);
        return messageRepository.save(message);
    }

public Message updateMessage(String messageId, @Valid MessageRequestDTO messageRequestDTO) throws MessageNotFoundException {
        Message existingMessage = messageRepository.findById(messageId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new MessageNotFoundException("Message not found with ID: " + messageId));

        List<MessageImage> messageImages = messageRequestDTO.getImages().stream()
                .map(messageMapper::toMessageImageEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Message updatedMessage = existingMessage.toBuilder()
                .text(messageRequestDTO.getText())
                .to(messageRequestDTO.getTo())
                .from(messageRequestDTO.getFrom())
                .requestId(messageRequestDTO.getRequestId())
                .images(messageImages)
                .offer(messageRequestDTO.getOffer())
                .build();

        return messageRepository.save(updatedMessage);
    }

public Message saveMessageImageAndSend(
            ImageSaveRequestDTO imageSaveRequestDTO,
            String imageAccessToken,
            String iAutoToken,
            String phone,
            String accept
    ) throws MessageNotFoundException {
        Message rawMessage = createMessage(MessageRequestDTO.builder()
                .from(imageSaveRequestDTO.getFrom())
                .to(imageSaveRequestDTO.getTo())
                .requestId(imageSaveRequestDTO.getRequest_id())
                .messageType(MessageType.IMAGE)
                .text("File")
                .build());
        String messageId = rawMessage.getId();
        imageSaveRequestDTO.setMessage_id(messageId);

        List<MessageImage> messageImages = messageImageService.uploadImages(imageSaveRequestDTO, imageAccessToken, iAutoToken, phone, accept);
        rawMessage.setImages(messageImages);
        return updateMessage(rawMessage.getId(), messageMapper.toRequestDTO(rawMessage));
    }

}

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MessageImageService {
    private final ImageFeignClient imageFeignClient;

    public List<MessageImage> uploadImages(ImageSaveRequestDTO imageSaveRequestDTO,
                                                  String imageAccessToken,
                                                  String iAutoToken,
                                                  String phone,
                                                  String accept) {
        ResponseEntity<List<List<ImageResponseDTO>>> imageServiceResponse = imageFeignClient.saveImage(imageSaveRequestDTO, imageAccessToken, iAutoToken, phone, accept);
        if (!imageServiceResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.CREATED)) {
            log.error("Failed to send image via message - received image service error");
            throw new RuntimeException("Image service failed.");
        }

        return imageServiceResponse.getBody().stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(imageData -> MessageImage.builder()
                        .id(imageData.getId())
                        .requestId(imageData.getRequestId())
                        .messageId(imageSaveRequestDTO.getMessage_id())
                        .imageUrl(imageData.getImageUrl())
                        .imageThumbUrl(imageData.getImageThumbUrl())
                        .text(imageData.getText())
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

During execution of code, I get message not found exception. During debugging I see very interesting moment - raw message is created and has id, imgage is uploaded succcessfuly, but when I evaluate messageRepository.findById(messageId), I get empty optional and while debuggir is paused I dont see any new document in messages collection. I dodnt have much experience with Mongodb, but for me it looks like transactional problem - database updates arent flushed in time and during update there is no new doc in collection. But I can be wrong. I tried to put @Transactional annotation, but it didn't help. Why raw message isn't persisted and how to make mongodb to save it in time?

Have you tried saveAndFlush?

I'm using MongoDB. Spring-data-mongodb does not have saveAndFlush() method. its available only for SQL databases

Maby you could share the logs by inserting systemLog.verbosity: 3 to MongoDB's config.cfg to see whats going on
